# if else statement with Checkbox not executing as expected

Tags: android, checkbox

I have problems when using a `CheckBox` in an `else if` statement. I have a `CheckBox` list like:

```
cbapel, cbmangga, cbjeruk, cbbelimbing.
```

when I tick the checkBoxes `cbapel`, `cbmangga`, and `cbjeruk` the result is "2" instead of "4". What's the solution?

```
    if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbbelimbing.isChecked()) {
     tx.setText("1");}
else if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()) {
     tx.setText("2");}
else if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbmangga.isChecked()) {
     tx.setText("3");}
 else if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbmangga.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()) {
     tx.setText("4");}
 else {
     tx.setText("NOT FOUND");
 }
```

Comment: Why do you repeatedly check `MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked()`? Move that to an if statement surrounding this whole block

Comment: can you post the sample input output?  i am not getting it what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really overlooking the simple solution here, by far (assuming you are just counting the number of checked boxes)

```
int checked = 0;
if (MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked()) {
    checked++;
}

if (MainActivity.cbbelimbing.isChecked()) {
    checked++;
}

if (MainActivity.cbmangga.isChecked()) {
    checked++;
}

if (MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()) {
    checked++;
}

if (checked == 0) {
     tx.setText("NOT FOUND");
} else {
     tx.setText(String.valueOf(checked));   
}
```

---

If you aren't looking to count the checkboxes, then I think this follows the same logic as what you tried in your question, but accounts for one condition ever being entered.

```
String value = "";

boolean bool1 = MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked();
boolean bool2 = MainActivity.cbbelimbing.isChecked();
boolean bool3 = MainActivity.cbmangga.isChecked();
boolean bool4 = MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked();

if (bool1) {

    if (bool3 && bool4) {
        value = "4";    
    } else if (bool3 && !bool4) {
        value = "3";
    } else if (!bool3 && bool4) {
        value = "2";
    }

    if (value.isEmpty() && bool2) {
        value = "1";
    }
} else {
    value = "NOT FOUND";
}

tx.setText(value.isEmpty() ? "NOT FOUND" : value);
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't necessarily want to set the text to the # of boxes checked. So, if `cbmangga.isChecked()` it should just be "3". But what if that and `cbjeruk.isChecked()`? I think the OP really needs a better design because this kind of looks more like `RadioButtons` maybe?

Comment: @Alfiansyah - No, I will not correct your pastebin links

Comment: @codeMagic - As far as I can tell, there are 4 checkboxes. From the question if `cbapel` is checked, **then** set the numbers? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes but I'm saying that my guess is that the text that should be set doesn't necessarily match the number of check boxes ticked. I'm also saying that the question doesn't really give enough detail for a complete solution ( which I think I asked OP for) so I'm walking away for now :)

Comment: @Alfiansyah - If you **explain** what the numbers in the textView represent in terms of the checkboxes, then I will update my answer (since it seems that this isn't what you asked for)

Comment: @Alfiansyah - Okay... then there is no significance to which checkboxes are checked and what number appears in the textbox? Because your question seemed to say you wanted a certain number to appear when certain checkboxes are checked

Comment: @Alfiansyah - Look, I understand if english isn't your main language, but  statements like "how do I fix this" aren't helping me understand what you want to do.

Comment: I just wanted to checked if cbapel and cbbelimbing = 1, if cbapel and cbbelimbing and cbjeruk = 2.  Number is textview

Comment: @Alfiansyah - With the new edits, `cbmangga` and `cbjeruk` and `cbapel` being checked will set it to 4. Not sure what you wanted for the other conditions...

Comment: i try, cbapel, cbmangga, cbjeruk result "4" yes.but why i try cbapel, cbmangga, cbbelimbing reuslt "3" should result "not found"

Comment: I recommend you draw a diagram for every combination of your checkboxes and circle all the paths of checked boxes that lead to a number that you want, then code `if (that checked) { if (this checked) { if (another checked) { "number" } else { "not found" } } else { "number" }`... just a giant nested if-statement. Forget about `else if`. Otherwise, I don't understand the logic of this

Comment: digram: if cbapel and cbbelimbing = 1, if cbapel and cbjeruk = 2, if cbapel and cbmangga = 3, if cbapel,cbmangga, and cbjeruk = 4. beside that "not found". but when i try cbapel, cbmangga and cbbelimbing = 3, i wish result not found.

Comment: @Alfiansyah - Thank you. One second.

Comment: @Alfiansyah - See if the new edit is close, please, I haven't been testing this

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks i can try and modify my code. thanks full

Answer (score 1):

`else if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()) {`

Let's look at this...

Is `MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked()`? Yes

Is `MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()`? Yes

So this evaluates to `true` and so it won't check any of the other conditional statements.

There are many different ways for this logic to flow. But, to know what is best for your situation, depends on what these variables *actually mean* and what you are doing.

The best advice I could give you from what you have provided is to check the most filtered situation first. So...

```
if(MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() && MainActivity.cbmangga.isChecked() 
    && MainActivity.cbjeruk.isChecked()) {
        tx.setText("4");
}
```

then add the `else if`s after that for the other checks.

Also, [cricket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) has a good suggestion in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355275/statement-if-else-checkbox-android/35355360#comment58417287_35355275) you are checking the same condition every time so you can remove that and wrap it all in one `if` to remove some duplication.

Comment: MainActivity.cbapel.isChecked() because checkbox located in mainactivity and result texview in main2activity

Comment: BTW, that isn't the most filtered situation you've shown there. You missed a checkbox

Comment: @cricket_007 how? The last one checks 3 CheckBoxes. That should go first unless I'm missing something

Comment: @Alfiansyah I don't understand your comment at all

Comment: @codeMagic - You are checking 3 checkboxes, and setting the text to 4. Anyways, my answer is much cleaner

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not trying to argue;just trying to see what I missed. Anyway, I'm not sure that the number of boxes checked is supposed to correlate with the text. I don't really know what the OP is after since he hasn't clarified. Anyway, your solution (if desired here) is cleaner so enjoy another 10 points :)

Comment: when I tick the CheckBoxes cbapel, cbmangga, and cbjeruk the result is "2" .
should "4". What's the solution?

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks. But, yeah, not trying to argue. I see from the question now that the text does indeed not correlate to the number of checked boxes

Comment: i'm sorry, i was just confused

Comment: @Alfiansyah that's fine. I still think my answer will fix your immediate issue. But, I do think there is probably a design and logic flaw elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use this listener to each check box and set your conditions accordingly

class CheckboxListeners implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

```
    private CheckBox checkbox;

    CheckboxListeners(CheckBox checkbox) {
        this.checkbox = checkbox;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        checkbox.setChecked(isChecked);

    }


}
```